# Do I need react-scripts if I use create-react-app

Tags: docker, create-react-app, nodemon

I want to run my create-react-app in docker. I create react-app. Write `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10.13.0

RUN mkdir /frontend

WORKDIR /frontend

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 9000

# CMD npm start - (1)
# CMD nodemon start - (2)
# CMD nodemon ./src/index.js - (3)
```

I don't install node_modules and don't copy all file into image because I'll do this with volumes. Then I create a `dockerfile`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  frontend-dev:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

OK. Now I uncomment (1) in my Dockerfile.dev (now last 3 lines are commented) and run

```
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml build
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml up
```

And there is an error 'react-scripts not found'. OK. It's because I don't run `npm install`. I want to exec `npm install` inside container. **But after this error my container stopped and I can't to exec this command.** OK! I heard from one man that I can use `nodemon` to start my app and if there is error - my container wouldn't be stopped.

Ok. Let`s comment (1) and uncomment (2). Than run

```
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml down
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml build
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml up
```

And.. the same problem... Container has stopped. Ok! I think it is because `script` by default do `react-scripts start`. Maybe this `react-scripts` reason of failure? Lets comment (2) and uncomment (3), run `

```
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml down
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml build
docker-compose -f dockerfile.dev.yml up
```

It's works?.. No.. Container hasn't stopped. So, I can run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml exec frontend-dev npm install
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml restart frontend-dev
```

But it wouldn't work because I have another error:

```
frontend-dev_1  | /frontend/src/index.js:1
frontend-dev_1  | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
frontend-dev_1  |                                                                          ^^^^^
frontend-dev_1  | 
frontend-dev_1  | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
frontend-dev_1  |     at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
frontend-dev_1  |     at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Module._compile     (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
frontend-dev_1  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
frontend-dev_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
frontend-dev_1  |     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
frontend-dev_1  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't know what I do, I don't know what I need.. Am I need this 'react-scripts'? What they are do? Is `react-script` really important? How can I run my app with docker? Maybe (2) way was right and I just need fix other small thing?.. Please help me.